# Bind @Observable model property to @ObservableObject model property so view updates?

Tags: swiftui

I have the following demo code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Observation

class Car1: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rentDate:Date = .now
}

class Car2: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rentDate:Date = .now
}

@Observable class CarViewModel {
    var rentDate:Date = .now
}

struct CarView: View {
    @State var model = CarViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("DATE: \(model.rentDate)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var car1 = Car1()
    @StateObject var car2 = Car2()
    @State var model = CarViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var model = model
        
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        /// I want model.rentDate to update as car1.rentDate updates...
                        model.rentDate = car1.rentDate
                        
                        //tried this:
                        /// Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<Date>' to type 'Date' but gives `model.rentDate = $car1.rentDate`
                    } label: {
                        Text("Bind to Car1")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        /// I want model.rentDate to update as car2.rentDate updates...
                        model.rentDate = car2.rentDate
                    } label: {
                        Text("Bind to Car2")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        /// when I change this I want `Text("DATE: \(model.rentDate)")` below to update...
                        car1.rentDate = .now
                    } label: {
                        Text("Change Car1")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        /// when I change this I want `Text("DATE: \(model.rentDate)")` below to update...
                        car2.rentDate = .now
                    } label: {
                        Text("Change Car2")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text("DATE: \(model.rentDate)")
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

I want CarViewModel `rentDate` to bind to either Car1 or Car2  rentDate so that when the model layer in other parts of the app changes car2.rentDate the change also shows up in ContentView `Text("DATE: \(model.rentDate)")` and this allows me to have a view model that can work with different dates found in other models...

Basically I am trying to have a way to bind a model to follow another model. In my case the one that drives the view uses `@Observable` and the other models use `ObservableObject`...

This is just some demo code I would like to get working to prove the functionality. So I would click on "Bind to Car1" and then tapping on "Change Car1" would trigger the date at the bottom to update based on car1 model.rentDate. Same for car2...

How can I get `CarViewModel` to follow either car1 or car2 model?

Comment: I see no reason to mix Observable and ObservableObject since they solve the same problem and the former replaces the latter.

Comment: It also not clear from your demo what the logic is for updating the date in the view model, is it always ment to hold the latest update from your Car1, Car2 objects? Overall I find the demo code a bit confusing.

Comment: Observable replaces ObservableObject. Unless you are breaking down code into a Business layer or a Service layer that uses combine there is no need for ObservableObject.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have models in my project that use both because I have not migrated ObservableObject to Observable. That is why I have both here.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the objective is to have CarViewModel either follow Car1 or Car2. So I am trying to make it so when I tap on Bind to Car2 tapping on Change Car2 would cause the text to update showing the date from Car2.

Comment: no need for those `Bind to car` buttons, just add `model.rentDate = car1.rentDate` after `car1.rentDate = .now`, same for car2.

Comment: I'm trying to make CarViewModel follow one of the car1 or car2 models at the time. Doing what you suggested is just handling case by case manually. I am trying to see if there is a way to have CarViewModel rentDate update automatically to either car1's rentDate or car2's rentDate... when one of them changes (one at the time not both at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue in the provided code snippet is that the CarViewModel class does not directly conform to the ObservableObject protocol. @Published property cannot be used to observe changes to the rentDate variable within CarViewModel.Moreover, it's crucial to utilize the @ObservedObject attribute for instances of Car1, Car2, and CarViewModel since the @StateObject attribute is meant to be used exclusively within the ContentView.

Comment: `@Observable class CarViewModel` is observed using the `Observation` framework, 
 it replaces `ObservableObject`, it is a newer/better version of it.
 see:
 [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app).

Answer (score 0):

Since this is SwiftUI you need to make `View` structs for your car and not view model objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach using the NotificationCenter, `...to make CarViewModel follow one of the car1 or car2 models at the time`.

The example code shows how to automatically "send" (in didSet) a notification to the `CarViewModel` whenever Car1 or Car2 `rentDate` changes, thus updating the CarViewModel `rentDate` automatically.

EDIT-1

Here is a more complete example of choosing which car you want to `bind to`

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Observation

class Car1: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rentDate: Date = .now {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: CarViewModel.rentNotification,
                object: (rentDate, "car1")
            )
        }
    }
}

class Car2: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rentDate: Date = .now {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: CarViewModel.rentNotification,
                object: (rentDate, "car2")
            )
        }
    }
}

@Observable class CarViewModel {
    var rentDate: Date = .now
    var carType: String = ""
    
    public static let rentNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue: "rent")
    
    init() {
         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: CarViewModel.rentNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, using: rentDateUpdate)
    }
    
    // this function is called whenever a rentNotification is received
    func rentDateUpdate(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let (date, car) = notification.object as? (Date, String) {
            if carType == car {
                rentDate = date
            }
        }
    }

    func bindTo(_ car: String) {
        carType = car
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var car1 = Car1()
    @StateObject var car2 = Car2()
    @State var model = CarViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Bind to Car1") {
                        model.bindTo("car1")
                    }.foregroundColor(model.carType == "car1" ? .red : .blue)
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Bind to Car2") {
                        model.bindTo("car2")
                    }.foregroundColor(model.carType == "car2" ? .red : .blue)
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Change Car1") {
                        car1.rentDate = .now
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Change Car2") {
                        car2.rentDate = .now
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
                Text("model.rentDate: \(model.rentDate)")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```